# add more admin and allow permission in magento site

Tags: magento

Hai

I want to create more users as admin and allow permission to access some modules. I know it's possible, but I don't know how is it? Does any one know? Please give me the steps. Does any one help me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explore the following Admin sections

1. System -> Permissions -> Users
2. System -> Permissions -> Roles

and come back with specific questions. "Show me the steps" is overtly broad.